# SSL/TLS 1.2 Connection Issues - PHP 5.6/SQLSRV 3.2

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, sqlsrv

I trying to make an old PHP application run on TLS 1.2. I found a similar thread ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45146979/ssl-tls-1-2-connection-issues-php-sqlsrv)) and made sure my driver works with TLS 1.2 but I still get the error. From the error, I assume it's not even reaching the server and failing at the client-side.

"[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Encryption not supported on the client."

I have below setup

- PHP version 5.6
- MS ODBC Driver 11 (Checked PShell script mentioned by @Rohith and it supports TLS 1.2)
- SQLSRV v3.2
- MS SQL Server 2012
- MS Windows 2012 R2

Not sure If its SQLSRV 3.2 does not support TLS 1.2 or its PHP 5.6 or something else?

Appreciate any help

Comment: Not only does the driver need to talk TLS v1.2 but the client and the server both need to share at least one ciphersuite. If you `openssl s_client -host YourSqlServer -port 1433 -tls1_2 -security_debug_verbose` do you see any offered ciphersuites that your client machine has installed?

Comment: Also... SQLSRV 3.2 is from 2015. Have you considered updating your stack?

Comment: SQL Server is set to default, which from what I'm reading on Windows 2012 means enabled by default and supports all cipher suites.